# Fail to run AWS pipeline after merging to development environment from bitbucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, webpack, aws-codebuild

I'm having issues to run the a pipeline in AWS successfully. The flow fails in the CodeBuild phase of AWS.
I thought it was due to the .npm installation but I double checked and that is ok.
Please find below the tail log.
Thank you!

```html
Build failed because of webpack errors
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tokyo-white-nextjs-admin-dashboard@3.0.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the tokyo-white-nextjs-admin-dashboard@3.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-26T08_22_32_253Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tokyo-white-nextjs-admin-dashboard@3.0.0 build-prod: `npm run clean && npm run build && npm run export`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the tokyo-white-nextjs-admin-dashboard@3.0.0 build-prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-26T08_22_32_267Z-debug.log

[Container] 2022/04/26 08:22:32 Command did not exit successfully npm run build-prod exit status 1
[Container] 2022/04/26 08:22:32 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2022/04/26 08:22:32 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run build-prod. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2022/04/26 08:22:32 Entering phase POST_BUILD
```

Comment: Can you share the content of the log file in error message ? log file `/root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-26T08_22_32_267Z-debug.log` ?

Comment: Hi @VincentDoba thank you for assisting here! I'm trying to find these logs details but I'm struggling. Do you have any idea? Best, Claudia!